# RCaller package issue

Tags: java, r

Tried *Listing 3: Simple Call* from
https://github.com/jbytecode/rcaller/blob/master/doc/rcaller3/rcaller3.pdf

however, I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.rcaller.exception.ExecutionException: Can not run C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.1\bin\Rscript.exe. Reason: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at com.github.rcaller.rstuff.RCaller.runRCode(RCaller.java:263)
    at com.github.rcaller.rstuff.RCaller.runAndReturnResult(RCaller.java:574)
    at RCallerPract.main(RCallerPract.java:12)
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with R not running, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

(Running this on IntelliJ, got RCaller through built in function in IntelliJ ( File -> Project Structure -> got Maven Package of RCaller)

I looked into something called "Ruinversal", but it said that my version of R isn't correct. If by chance this is the solution can someone tell me how to get it on a platform that would allow me to run in in IntelliJ?

Comment: Looks like the path needs to be quoted - it's trying to run `C:\Program` because of the space in `Program Files`.

Comment: (Side comment: I hadn't heard of rcaller before, so I looked at the github page. I find contradictory phrases such as *"it is very simple to use and its learning curve is steep"* to be a bit disconcerting.) (Sorry, not a java coder.)

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen do you know a way to fix the issue/How do you quote a path? Probably a really basic question but I'm quite new to R.